# How to give preference to a particular index while searching through multiple indices in thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am using Thinking Sphinx with rails 5.2.2. I need to give preference to data of one index than the other, while searching through multiple indices, in the final output.
For example I have an index `index1` with an attribute `attr = foo` and an other index `index2` with an attribute `attr = foo`. What I want is, `ThinkingSphinx.search` should always return data from `index2` if `attr` matches `foo`(or some other value). If there is no record with `attr` matching `foo` in `index2` records from `index1` should be returned.
Note: I need to group the result on `attr`

Here is an example of a query I am using.

```
ThinkingSphinx.search("@attr =foo|foo*", group_by: :attr, middleware: ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::RAW_ONLY, indices: ['index1', 'index2'])
```

According to [this documentation](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)(Searching Multiple Indexes) data from later index (index2 in this case) should be returned. But some records are being returned from  `index1` and some are being returned from `index2`.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx doesn't have a direct concept of prioritising one index over another, but you could add an attribute to each model to indicate importance, and then sort by that?

In the index definition:

```
# SQL-backed indices:
has "1", as: :priority

# Or, real-time indices:
has priority
# And add a method to each model returning an appropriate integer
```

And then searching:

```
ThinkingSphinx.search(
  "@attr =foo|foo*",
  group_by: :attr,
  middleware: ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::RAW_ONLY,
  indices: ['index1', 'index2'],
  select: '*, weight() as w',
  order: 'priority ASC, w DESC'
)
```